# How to align the button in Gtkmm?

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I am using Ubuntu OS.

I am new to GTKMM GUI building application.
I am following the tutorials which they have on their websites.

`https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-helloworld.html.en`

I can resize the window with `helloworld.set_default_size(500,500);`

but I cannot move the position of button("hello world").

It is always aligned at center.

I tried with `m_button.set_alignment(0.0,0.0)` but nothing seems to be working.

Why it is that much difficult to move button to any position.?

kindly suggest some solution if available.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place a widget like a button, you have to use some container widget like `Gtk::Box`or `Gtk::Grid`. Inside such container widgets you can place you child widget as you like, but typically *not* directly per point position.

The container widgets use some internal logic to order and resize the contained widgets.

From the documentation:

> Many GUI toolkits require you to precisely place widgets in a window, using absolute positioning, often using a visual editor. This leads to several problems: ...
>   gtkmm uses the packing system to solve these problems.

You can find the full documentation here:
[Multi-item widgets](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-multi-item-containers.html.en)

I did not know if there is a container widget which allows direct positioning by giving a point position. If someone has an additional hint, let us know!

Sometimes automatic is better than manual handling, but sometimes it is not :-)

Comment: Concerning _I did not know if there is a container widget which allows direct positioning by giving a point position._: Are you looking for [`Gtk::Fixed`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Fixed.html)?